Xcode error Sandbox: il2cpp(17473) deny(1) file-read-data
I got the following error in Xcode:　”Sandbox: il2cpp(17473) deny(1) file-read-data".
What should I do?
Xcode version is 16. Unity version is 2022.3.6f1.
I checked the Unity build settings and found nothing wrong.
This issue may occur if your Xcode project is improperly configured. In particular, check that the required frameworks are linked correctly in the Build Phases.
